# What kind of evidence should be given for "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it "

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

Recently, I have flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18860329/1771402) answer for moderator attention, with this message:

> It does not add anything more to the existing answers.It was like copy
>   paste from existing answers after 1 year

It does not provide anything extra than the already existing answers. But my flag got rejected saying that:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

Then I found that I flagged with the wrong reason. The question was asked to get text from an inflated `EditBox`, but the answer was given to get it from an `EditBox` that is not inflated.

Now I need to flag this answer as low-quality. What kind of evidence should I add so that it would help moderators accept it?

Comment: `The Question was asked to get text from inflated EditBox, but answer was given to get from Editbox which is not inflated` You're saying that it's an inaccurate answer: it's not the job of mods to judge the technical accuracy of answers. You can add a comment and/or downvote.

Comment: Why can't you just downvote the answer?  Use the moderator flags when something *serious* has transpired.

Comment: I had already down voted, then how can we put these kind of answers to  low-quality review queue

Comment: Why do you *need* to put the answer into the low-quality review queue? Is it really that low-quality that it warrants review from other users/mods? This all seems much ado about nothing to me frankly. As mentioned, it's simply an inaccurate answer. Since you've downvoted it, there is nothing more that you need to do. If you care about the answer so much you can leave a comment explaining why it is wrong, how to correct it, etc.

Comment: The answer was providing incorrect solution which will not work in OP's case. Also there was 2 other answers which will work for OP's case. When a third answer comes after several days , i think it should be covering anything which was not covered in previous answers and not simply just copy paste of two lines.

Comment: @BoltClock sorry, i think i should have first left a comment in that answer.Thanks for explaining me the process

Comment: When you say "It was like copy paste from existing answers", do you mean it was copied from elsewhere on Stack Overflow without attribution? If so, that's flaggable, but as Patrick says you should cite the URL of the original post in your moderator report.

Comment: @krishna: voting to delete...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you say

> It was like copy paste from existing answers after 1 year.

It is best to include a link to the answer you are referring to. The moderators don't have the time to search the copied answer themselves. You have to supply it to the to handle the flag effectively.

Also, answering after a year doesn't mean it is bad. If I was searching for a problem, tried all supplied answers and found out they didn't work for me, it is very good to create a new answer for future googles.

Comment: It is good to create new answer which really works, but the answer was not addressing the problem faced by OP.  Thanks for mentioning how to add evidence when i was flagging to moderator

Comment: I can't judge that since I am not familiar with the technology, but for low quality answers we have downvotes in place (note that very low quality answers should be flagged).

Comment: You mean the one with more downvotes as very low quality ?

Comment: A bad answer doesn't mean it is a low quality answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: that is the definition of low-quality to me.

Comment: Low quality means just a single line of text with a link, or a code block without explanation.

Answer (score 10):

You should not be using flags to indicate wrong answers.

You should be using a down-vote (with optional comment) to indicate wrong answers.

Comment: or delete vote over 20K ...

Comment: per my reading, answer being wrong or correct doesn't matter in this case, what matters is that it repeats another answer posted long before it. Whether the original answer is correct or wrong is also irrelevant from flagging perspective (because, as you pointed, flagging isn't for wrong answers). I think one can say that flagged answer is _provably useless_, maybe up to the point of being harmful (lowering signal/noise), the question is, whether this is a flaggable abuse or not