# Flag was declined--no evidence to support it

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364465/differences-between-abc-de-and-abc-de-de-de-in-java). At first, I didn't express my meaning clearly and some users think my question is the duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and I made some edit, flag it for moderator. But result is

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Could anyone explain it to me: why my question is still thought duplicate?

**Related:** [What kind of evidence should be given for “a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261312/what-kind-of-evidence-should-be-given-for-a-moderator-reviewed-your-flag-but-f)

Comment: You should not flag for mod attention in such cases. Mod flags are for serious issues. Reopening a question is handled by the community.

Comment: You have made a correct decision to edit & clarify the question. Now, please wait for community to vote to reopen your question. (Hope for meta effect!)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Sorry, but I don't understand if someone else also has the same issue, what should they do?

Comment: When you edited it, the edit bumped the question back to the front page. So, it gets fresh views and community can vote to reopen the question (if they feel it's not a dupe). What you should do is wait after editing. Also, it can get reopened due to Meta effect, as this meta question will make a lot of people to look into your question. Flagging is for an entirely different purpose. It is for cleaning up the site (removing bad stuff), not for reopening questions.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of how to compare Strings, but I feel like I've seen this question before somewhere...In either event, that wouldn't be a good thing to flag for moderator attention; they're really there to handle exceptional cases that the community normally can't.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Thanks for your guide. But it is hard for a question marked duplicate to get fresh views, actually.

Comment: Yes, it's not a dupe. I wrote the answer in comments of your question, as I can't cast a reopen vote yet. Hope that helps you understand why you got different outputs. As for views, editing does get views. That's for sure :-)

Comment: well, I am not a Java expert but your question sounds like a variation of "how to compare strings in java" so I can understand why someone voted as a duplicate.

Comment: @mehow But that question ask the differences between `==` and `equal()` that is totally different from my question. They shouldn't judge from title.

Comment: Tony, if you understood what value and reference types were and how to compare them in the first place you would never arrive at your question therefore to me it's a duplicate.

Comment: @mehow Sorry, I do understand value should use `equals()` and reference should use '==' for `String` but I don't know why this can solve my that question. Any guidances here?

Comment: @mehow That doesn't make any sense. Just because you think someone should understand something already and not ask a question doesn't mean that their question is a duplicate of anything tangentially related that you think they should be able to extrapolate from... maybe there is a duplicate somewhere but that question wasn't one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you combine every moderator on the site into a single person, then you have someone that has *probably* 80% of the domain knowledge stored in Stack Overflow. Separately, it varies, and it can vary wildly.

Duplicates are a somewhat subjective call, sometimes *very closely related* can easily be misinterpreted as *pretty much the same*. The key difference lies in the answers your question received, and those .. well, clearly speak to the *why* and not the *how*, and you've indicated that you know the *how* but not the *why* within the question. As such, I've reopened it, even though it is sufficiently answered. The community *can* overrule me if they want, but I think it's different enough to remain open.

"Declined" in this sense just means "I'm not convinced that this isn't a duplicate". Stack Overflow moderators *absolutely can not* leave flags soaking in the queue or you just end up with thousands of flags that at least one moderator doesn't want to deal with. They take action, to the best of their ability because they know you can come here to meta if they take an action that they shouldn't have, or didn't take an action that they should have.

Think of it more like "More than one person needs to make this decision, it can't rest only on me". At that point your source of support comes from the community, instead of a single moderator, and that's precisely how it should work.

Comment: Thanks, and it seems that I learn from comment that I shouldn't bother moderator in this case.

Comment: One more question: can I edit the question now to make it shorter by cutting some assembly code.